# pyramid_mailer subject header issue

Tags: python, email, pyramid

When I send email using pyramid_mailer in gmail web client all looks fine, but in any desktop clients `subject` contains question marks, for example:
[image]

If open source code of email `subject` header looks like:

```
Subject: =?utf-8?b?W9CS0LXQsS3Qk9CY0KEt0LrQvtC70YzRhtC10LLQsNC90LjQtV0g0JDQvdC+0L3Q?=
 =?utf-8?b?uNC8IDIwMTItMTAtMTggMTc6NTg6MzIg0YHQvtC30LTQsNC7INC30LDQv9C40YHR?=
 =?utf-8?b?jCAjMTM1OSAo0LrQvtC70YzRhtC10LLQsNC90LjQtSk=?=
```

As you can see it is splitted into three parts. Try to perform the python code:

```
import email.header
print email.header.decode_header('=?utf-8?b?W9CS0LXQsS3Qk9CY0KEt0LrQvtC70YzRhtC10LLQsNC90LjQtV0g0JDQvdC+0L3Q?=')[0][0]
print email.header.decode_header('=?utf-8?b?uNC8IDIwMTItMTAtMTggMTc6NTg6MzIg0YHQvtC30LTQsNC7INC30LDQv9C40YHR?=')[0][0]
print email.header.decode_header('=?utf-8?b?jCAjMTM1OSAo0LrQvtC70YzRhtC10LLQsNC90LjQtSk=?=')[0][0]
```

We are getting the following result:

```
[Веб-ГИС-кольцевание] Анон
�м 2012-10-18 17:58:32 создал запис
� #1359 (кольцевание)
```

How I can get rid of this issue?

Comment: You might want to try posting to the pyramid_mailer issue tracker at http://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_mailer/issues for more help. It smells like a bug.

Comment: [Reported](https://github.com/repoze/repoze.sendmail/issues/13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just [committed a fix](https://github.com/repoze/repoze.sendmail/pull/18) for this so you should be able to get it in repoze.sendmail 4.0 or 4.0b2, whichever is the next release.

Answer (score 0):

yep .. sounds like a bug to me too... python base64.encodestring() splits long strings be default into multiple lines, which i guess is causing the problem.

solution would be to replace the newlines in the used subjects or use binascii.b2a_base64 for encoding..

Comment: This isn't happening in `base64` but in `email.charset` from [this issue](https://github.com/repoze/repoze.sendmail/issues/13).